# Plotting 2D vector fields with colorscale in Plotly

Tags: python, plot, plotly, 2d

I would like to to plot a 2D vector field with plotly. I tried to use a quiver plot for this. However, it seems then it is not possible to encode the magnitude of the vector on a colorscale unless I create a new trace for every single vector. Interestingly, it seems easier in 3D where there is the cone plot as in this example: https://plotly.com/python/cone-plot/#3d-cone-vortex.

What would be the 2D equivalent for this?

EDIT: What I have tried sofar. One possibility that actually works is just using a 3D plot and just projecting the data into a plane. However, this is of course not a real 2D plot and I am looking for something better. Another approach I took was looking into the keyword arguments of plotly.graph_objects.Scatter as suggested by the documentation. There you have an argument called "line" but it seems that this is a single trace and I can only give it one color.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: A possible workaround is to define new traces for a group of vectors instead of one for each vector as suggested [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-make-python-quiver-with-colorscale/41028). This [issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/581) tracks the support for this feature, sponsorship is required.